# NSTimer how to disable while timer is still active?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, ios5

I have created a timer,

```
   self.scanTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:TIMEOUT_SECONDS target:self selector:@selector(meInterrupted:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

and some point in time in my code, i feel to disable it before timeout happens, so that the meInterrupted not to be called?.  How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just call [self.scanTimer invalidate];  This will keep the timer from ever firing if it is called before the timer fires.

Comment: Ya das ist gut.